# Transforming Data Layout

Tags: excel, vba

With reference the sample raw data below i have an export that lists for each item on a quote the various prices for each break quantity. Unfortunately the data is arranged in rows. What i would like to achieve is following the user specifying a particular quote number for the associated data to be copied to a new sheet and the layout transformed as per the two examples below.

[image: Sample Raw Data]

If quote 1 is selected the data should be arranged with the various break quantities and prices vertically arranged with an empty row between items associated with quote 1. If the price break is null then it is excluded to avoid creating too many empty rows.

[image: Quote 1]

By the same process if the user selected quote 2 then the data would be arranged as below.

[image: Quote 2]

I am happy to use vba to transform the data based on the user input for which quote they wish to view but i an unable to sort out the logic / process to use

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro when you do it manually?

Comment: No i have no record a macro as the row numbers of the items associated with a quote can be anywhere in the list and the number of break quantities can vary with each item.